# Procedure based trigger for audit table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have 2 tables, one main table and one audit table.

```
create sequence dbo.users_seq;
create table dbo.users 
(
 id bigint primary key default(next value for dbo.users_seq),
 user_data nvarchar(max) not null check(isjson(user_data) = 1),
 timestamp datetime2 not null default sysdatetime(),
 updated_timestamp datetime2 not null default sysdatetime()
);

create sequence dbo.users_audit_seq;
create table dbo.users_audit
(
 id bigint primary key default(next value for dbo.users_audit_seq),
 users_id bigint not null, --id from `users` table
 old nvarchar(max) not null check(isjson(old) = 1), --original row from `users` table
 new nvarchar(max) not null check(isjson(new) = 1), --new row from `users` table
 updated_by varchar(100) not null, --username info
 timestamp datetime2 not null default sysdatetime()
);
```

I am looking to create a `for update` trigger on `users` main table which calls a generic procedure that could be used for other tables with similar audit table schema.

The generic procedure should write to it's audit table (`users` table should write to `users_audit` table but the same procedure should also work for `users2` table and write to `users2_audit` table).

Note : *Temporal tables* approach won't work

Comment: "Temporal tables approach won't work" because? It sounds like you are reinventing the wheel. Even if you go down this approach, I suggest you use a generic tool to generate triggers *specifically* for each table, rather than attempting to write one generic trigger for all tables

Comment: I guess, it is better to create trigger for every table you need and skip the attempts to create universal trigger, universal stored procedure, universall something

Comment: Other than swapping the word function for procedure, this appears identical to [your other question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72152276/function-based-trigger-for-audit-table)

Comment: Charlieface , Sergey 
not looking for a dynamic trigger, will have a trigger on every table but want considering the possibility of a dynamic procedure 

@Stu yes, I am new here but read that editing a question's context after some responses isn't recommended

Comment: @AbhiV you would have been fine here since that refers to someone proposing an answer, after which yes you should not move the goalposts, you only have comments on your other question though not any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will preface by saying that Temporal Tables or SQL Audit are far better for this kind of thing, and you are basically reinventing the wheel.

---

Be that as it may, the below should give you a good model for a trigger

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER TR_users ON users
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;  -- prevent issues with bad client drivers

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deleted)
    RETURN;  -- early bail-out

INSERT users_audit (users_id, old, new, updated_by)
SELECT
  ISNULL(i.id, d.id),
  i.user_data,
  d.user_data,
  SUSER_SNAME()
FROM inserted i
FULL JOIN deleted d ON d.id = i.id  -- full join to match by all primary key columns
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT i.user_data    -- add other columns here
    INTERSECT             -- because INTERSECT deals correctly with nulls
    SELECT d.user_data
);

go
```

If you want this code for each table, I strongly suggest that instead of trying to write a single dynamic trigger, you instead write a tool that can generate specific triggers and audit tables for each table. Note that primary keys may contain multiple columns and you need to match all of them.

Comment: thanks for your answer. this is very close to what is needed but can you help with using this only for updates on `users`, we don't need an audit for inserts/deletes.

Comment: Change to `AFTER UPDATE` and change `FULL JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` no other changes are necessary